# Whereabouts of Straw Hat Grand fleet members During wano? (spoiler warning)

Tags: one-piece

We know a few members of the Grand fleet are on official duties in reverie that is taking place at the same time as the wano arc. But what about the rest of them members that are full time pirates! Is wano arc too small for them to enter?

> For example: Since Bigmom has come to action and joined forces with Kaido. Doesn't hajiruddin's entry makes sense?

I mean they looked for support everywhere (even Marco) but not SHGF why?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since Oda likes big surprises, we can expect SHGF to make its entry in the upcoming chapters. Showing where the Grand Fleet is right now could be detrimental to any buildup or excitement in future events.

On the other hand, the Grand Fleet could have a difficult time finding out that the Strawhats are in Wano since news of their landing there were not spread anywhere and the only people knowing are Bm Pirates (since they followed them there) and probably the Sun Pirates since they know where Jinbe is goind.

Comment: wano was a destination set in zou. And everyone except luffys group had enough time to contact them. Not to mention there are Vivre cards for location someone and Transponder snails